# How to retrieve result set of a query from MySQL in java

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, arraylist

I am already connected to my database:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://instance23389.db.xeround.com:15296/Inventory","user","password");
PreparedStatement Statement = con.prepareStatement("Select * from inventory");
ResultSet result = Statement.executeQuery();
while(result.next()) {
    //What to put here?
}
```

This is the arraylist I want stored in that database:

```
static ArrayList<Product> Chart=new ArrayList<Product>();
```

And that has these objects stored in the arraylist:

```
double Total;
String name;
double quantity;
String unit;
double ProductPrice;
```

What is the general code I need to use to get the arraylist to be stored in the MySQL database?
What is the general code I need to use to get the arraylist out of the MySQL database?

Comment: I'm confused of what you really want. Do you want to getInfo or Insert info to the database?

Comment: [Getting data from a resultset](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/GetRsData.html)

Comment: but he also mentioned he needs to store the arraylist in the database.

Comment: I have the impression that you may have so many questions that [a JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) is maybe a more appropriate starting point than trying to cobble your program together with snippets you're going to collect here...  It's quite crucial you understand how your program will interact with the db, and that's pretty hard to capture in short answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a template of what to use for retrieving & populating the Arraylist `productList`

```
while (result.next()) {

    Product product = new Product();

    product.setTotal(result.getDouble("Total"));
    product.setName(result.getString("Name"));
    // etc.

    productList.add(product);
}
```

In the meantime, I invite you to have a look at:

http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not very clear, but I am guessing that you want something like:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

String host = "instance23389.db.xeround.com";
int port = 15296;
String dbName = "Inventory";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName;

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;

try {

  con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user","password");
  stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from inventory");
  ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
  while(result.next()) {
    Product prod = new Product();
    prod.setTotal(result.getDouble("total"));
    prod.setName(result.getString("name"));
    prod.setQuantity(result.getDouble("quantity"));
    prod.setUnit(result.getString("unit"));
    prod.setProductPrice(result.getDouble("product_price"));
    products.add(prod);
  }
} finally {
  if (stmt != null) {
    try { 
      stmt.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
  }
  if (con != null) {
    try { 
      con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    }
  }
}
return products;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert, then a select is not the way. What you need is something like

```
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Customers " + "VALUES (1001, 'Simpson', 'Mr.', 'Springfield', 2001)");
```